# Converting data frame from wide to long but with stacked rows as columns

Tags: r, reshape

I have a big database that I am working with about 1500 rows. I have a data frame in wide format but I want it to be in a long format but the columns need to be stacked as rows. I have tried using reshape package which helped but I need to get the columns into rows and label each row but the inbred name. I have a data frame ready to go...I have two data frame df is the starting point. df.actual is the data frame I am trying to get. I used the reshape function to stack the inbreds by column by the columns that need to be stacked again like the inbreds were.

```
 df<-data.frame(inbred=c("x1","x2","x3","x4"),trait1=c(12,43,23,65),obs1=c(2,2,3,2),std.error1=c(.2,.3,.2,.4)
                ,trait2=c(14,53,63,68),obs2=c(3,3,2,2),std.error2=c(.1,.4,.5,.6))
 df
  inbred trait1 obs1 std.error1 trait2 obs2 std.error2
1     x1     12    2        0.2     14    3        0.1
2     x2     43    2        0.3     53    3        0.4
3     x3     23    3        0.2     63    2        0.5
4     x4     65    2        0.4     68    2        0.6
>
```

I've tried getting the dataframe to reshape into wide but the columns weren't stacked.

```
 reshape(df, varying= c("trait1","obs1","std.error1","trait2","obs2","std.error2"),
         idvar = "inbred", direction="long", sep="")
     inbred time trait obs std.error
x1.1     x1    1    12   2       0.2
x2.1     x2    1    43   2       0.3
x3.1     x3    1    23   3       0.2
x4.1     x4    1    65   2       0.4
x1.2     x1    2    14   3       0.1
x2.2     x2    2    53   3       0.4
x3.2     x3    2    63   2       0.5
x4.2     x4    2    68   2       0.6
>
```

I am having trouble getting the dataframe to stack the rows and label these rows by there inbred name.

```
 df.actual = data.frame(inbred=c("x1","x1","x1","x2","x2","x2","x3","x3","x3","x4","x4","x4"),metric=c("data.entry","obs","std.error","data.entry","obs","std.error","data.entry","obs","std.error","data.entry","obs","std.error"),trait1=c(12,2,.2,43,2,.3,23,3,.2,65,2,.4),
                                 trait2=c(14,3,.1,53,3,.4,63,2,.5,68,2,.6))
 df.actual
   inbred     metric trait1 trait2
1      x1 data.entry   12.0   14.0
2      x1        obs    2.0    3.0
3      x1  std.error    0.2    0.1
4      x2 data.entry   43.0   53.0
5      x2        obs    2.0    3.0
6      x2  std.error    0.3    0.4
7      x3 data.entry   23.0   63.0
8      x3        obs    3.0    2.0
9      x3  std.error    0.2    0.5
10     x4 data.entry   65.0   68.0
11     x4        obs    2.0    2.0
12     x4  std.error    0.4    0.6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option with `pivot_longer` where we can get both the formats (second format) by interchanging the positions of `names_to`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) 
library(stringr)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -inbred, names_to = c("metric", ".value"),
    names_sep="(?<=[a-z])(?=\\d$)", 
     names_repair = ~ str_replace(., "^(\\d+)", "trait\\1")) %>%
  mutate(metric = replace(metric, metric == "trait", "data.entry"))
# A tibble: 12 x 4
#   inbred metric     trait1 trait2
#   <fct>  <chr>       <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 x1     data.entry   12     14  
# 2 x1     obs           2      3  
# 3 x1     std.error     0.2    0.1
# 4 x2     data.entry   43     53  
# 5 x2     obs           2      3  
# 6 x2     std.error     0.3    0.4
# 7 x3     data.entry   23     63  
# 8 x3     obs           3      2  
# 9 x3     std.error     0.2    0.5
#10 x4     data.entry   65     68  
#11 x4     obs           2      2  
#12 x4     std.error     0.4    0.6
```

---

If we need the `reshape` output

```
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -inbred, names_to = c(".value", "metric"),
    names_sep="(?<=[a-z])(?=\\d$)")
# A tibble: 8 x 5
#  inbred metric trait   obs std.error
#  <fct>  <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#1 x1     1         12     2       0.2
#2 x1     2         14     3       0.1
#3 x2     1         43     2       0.3
#4 x2     2         53     3       0.4
#5 x3     1         23     3       0.2
#6 x3     2         63     2       0.5
#7 x4     1         65     2       0.4
#8 x4     2         68     2       0.6
```

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there! The only thing that was missing was that there are two `"trait"s` in the data that you need to consider. The solution is to put the column groups into a list, which you can do by name or by number. I'll use numbers here.

To construct the desired `metrics` variable in the same step, use 1. `timevar` which gives the `time` variable a name, and 2. `times` which assigns names to the times (yielding type character though).

```
reshape(df, list(2:4, 5:7), idvar="inbred", direction="long", 
        timevar="metric", times=c("trait", "obs", "std.error"))
#              inbred    metric trait1 trait2
# x1.trait         x1     trait   12.0   14.0
# x2.trait         x2     trait   43.0   53.0
# x3.trait         x3     trait   23.0   63.0
# x4.trait         x4     trait   65.0   68.0
# x1.obs           x1       obs    2.0    3.0
# x2.obs           x2       obs    2.0    3.0
# x3.obs           x3       obs    3.0    2.0
# x4.obs           x4       obs    2.0    2.0
# x1.std.error     x1 std.error    0.2    0.1
# x2.std.error     x2 std.error    0.3    0.4
# x3.std.error     x3 std.error    0.2    0.5
# x4.std.error     x4 std.error    0.4    0.6
```

After that you could use  [`order()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1296745/6574038) to arrange the rows if needed.